# Why number of open file descriptor not increase?

Tags: c, linux

I have created a small C program to cross the system limit of open file descriptors in Linux. But i can see the threshold does not cross.

Here is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main()
{
  int i, fd[9000];
  for(i=0; i<9000; i++)
  {
   fd[i]=open("test.txt", O_RDWR);
  }
  while(1);
}
```

I would expect it to cross the limit and give me an error message. But if i run it in background and do `lsof | wc -l` it's not increasing.

What might be the reason?

Comment: Are you expecting the program or the system to print an error message? Why do you expect that rather than expecting `open` to return -1 to indicate failure, with no message to standard output or standard error?

Comment: How do you know it isn't failing on limit if you don't check `open`'s return value? (because it does)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I am checking `lsof` number and that's not increasing. by any chance more than 2k.

Comment: Maybe lsof reports on the system file table, and your test.txt file has an open/link count of somewhere between 0 and 9000. Or even larger. BTW: if you don't know what the tool (lsof) reports, why would you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Once your program reaches its limit of open files, the `open` call returns -1, and no more files are opened.

The program merely completes the `for` loop, failing to open any more files. No messages are displayed.

Per information extracted from the OP, the limit of open files for their processes is 1024. `lsof` shows about 2000 files open because there are 1024 for their process and approximately a thousand more for other processes in the system.

A process is limited to the number of files specified by its soft limit. The soft limit is “soft” because it can be change, to values up to the hard limit. However, until the soft limit is changed, it is the limit of the number of open files.

Comment: Then why do `lsof` not show the increase? I thght i mentioned it in question.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: `lsof` does not show any more files opened than the first 2000 because no more files are opened than the first 2000 (or whatever your limit is).

Comment: Didn't understand, if the threshold limit is 8k, why does the total number of open files `lsof` will show is only 2k?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 you haven't mentioned 8k before. Where does it came from? What's your `ulimit -n`?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: On your system, what does `ulimit -n` show for the limit on open files? If you modify your program to count and print how many of the calls return success (not -1) and how many return an error (-1), what does it print?

Comment: @keltar: Yes, the default size.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: “The default size” is not an answer to “What’s your `ulimit -n`?” An answer is a particular number, like 8192, 2048, or 256.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Agreed, that can be a method, but why `lsof` not show that is what confuses me.

Comment: Not sure if there is any 'default', but my `ulimit -n` == 1024

Comment: @kingsmasher1: We cannot solve the problem without data. Please modify your program as I described and report the results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil   :         `ulimit -n -H`
= 8192

Comment: @kingsmasher1 hard and soft limit are not the same. My guess is that your `ulimit -n` (or `ulimit -Sn`) is 2048.

Comment: @keltar: Why do you even care about soft limit?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 huh?.. well, please read e.g. http://serverfault.com/questions/265155/soft-limit-vs-hard-limit

Comment: @keltar: I know all these...i am trying to tell you, hardlimit is the upperlimit, so that's the limit should not cross by any chance. Softlimit we should not much care about.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Please execute `ulimit -n` and report the result, not `ulimit -n -H`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That's 1024 (ulimit -n)

Comment: @kingsmasher1 _please_ read article i referred to. It is NOT as you describe it. Soft limit is upper floor unless you _manually_ risen it

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I tried the same program with fd -1 return to print and exit, and it happens at Failed to allocate fd at: i=1021

Comment: @kingsmasher1 exactly because you've reached soft limit.... (1021+stdin+stdout+stderr==1024)

Comment: @keltar: DOesn't it consider the open file descriptors of various libraries, system calls etc? I mean the total fd (1024) should be = open fd my program + open fd by systems libraries, etc, right? How does it allow just a process to occupy that much limit?

Comment: @KillianDS: How can we find out if any process has the priviledge to go uptil the hardlimit or should it stop only at soft limit.

Comment: @kingsmasher1 as i recall, only root could change hard limit. As for shared libraries, i'm not sure about this one (nor would i come so close to limit, ever), and i believe this is a separate question. I suggest closing this question as Eric provided correct answer.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: I am unfamiliar with the details on Linux. However: Files opened by system processes should not count against your process’ limit. Files opened by library-loading mechanisms in your process (even if inserting by the linker or loader, not by you explicitly) should count against your process, but they might not remain open. I am not sure whether memory-mapped files count as open files.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not check return value of `open`. If you exceed limit of open descriptors, `open` returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EMFILE`.

<strike>Second, you are opening the same file. This may or may not count towards file descriptor limit.</strike>

Comment: It wont, if they had the same handle seeking would apply to both and such, they would represent the same file handle.

Answer (score 0):

You should close files , when you use `ulimit -n` , you'll see maximnum numbers of open files, you can change it via `ulimit -n NUMBER` or  `ulimit C function` from `ulimit.h`.

For your purpose you should use `int getrlimit(int resource, struct rlimit *rlim);`  function.

Comment: I think you haven't understood my question. Why will i close files, when my intention is to check for threshold limit?

Answer (score 0):

This one works, and `lsof ./test.txt | wc -l` reports 1021 successful opens. (The program itself as well.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  int i, fd[9000];
  for(i=0; i<9000; i++)
  {
   fd[i]=open("test.txt", O_RDWR| O_CREAT, 0644);
   if (fd[i] < 0) break;
  }
 fprintf(stderr, "I is now %d\n" , i);
  while(1);
  return 0;
}
```